# Auto capitalize text after space

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Is there any possibility to auto capitalize any word that begins after a space in the `AutoTextEditField` or in `EditField`?

Example:

> Company Is Blackberry

Or I should customize the `EditField`?

Comment: Implement a `FieldChangeListener`, register it to your `EditField` with `setChangeListener`. And convert the text of `EditField` on your implementation of `public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`. Use `setTex(String text)`, and `getText()` for manipulating `EditField`'s text.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, i implemented successfully